# How to match date with counter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to show for example:

```
Day 1 with Sun, 24 April 2016
Day 2 with Sun, 25 April 2016
Day 3 with Sun, 26 April 2016
etc...
```

All the dates however are being listed under each `days_challenged`.

```
    <% @challenge.days_challenged.times do |counter| %>
      <div class="text-background">
        Day <%= counter + 1 %>
        <%= @challenge.dates_challenged %>
        <%= render "notes/notes" %>
        <%= render "notes/form" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to loop them both together. For example:

```
<% @challenge.dates_challenged.first(@challenge.days_challenged).each_with_index do |date, i| %>
  <div class="text-background">
     Day <%= i + 1 %>
     <%= date %>
     <%= render "notes/notes" %>
     <%= render "notes/form" %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

That will take up to as many 'days challenged' entries and iterate over them.

Comment: Perfect! Yea I was trying two different iterations and getting all wacky stuff. Thanks for the knowledge :]

Comment: Normally in Ruby there's a simple way of doing it, so if you ever find yourself getting stuck in the weeds, have a look through the docs for [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html). There's a ton of very interesting tools in there.